Geometrical intuition of transfer function for scalar signals
The Laplace transform transform of a scalar valued function from the scalar time domain is as I understand it pretty much a particular (point, vector) pair of a 2d vector field over a surface. The locations being the s and the vectors of the field the F(s). Now I wonder how we can interpret the transfer function geometrically? Does it change the vector field in some intuitive way, maybe rotating the vectors towards the closest pole or something?
